# Invoking Javascript on VF Page from Static Resource

Tags: visualforce, javascript, static-resources

we have a Javascript sheet saved as a static resource and one of our developers is attempting to invoke a function from it in our visualforce page.

In our visualforce page, we are using:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.QA_Javascript}"/>
```

And we are trying to call a function for an onlabelclick on a pageBlockSection Item.

When we put the function in the top of the page within `<script>` tags it works fine, but we are trying to avoid that to keep the page cleaner. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: QA_Jacascript is a single JS file or a JS file inside of a zip?

Comment: At this point a single file, thats why we didn't use the URLFOR

Comment: have you tried to invoke the function by using onclick="QA_Javascript.function();" ( assuming the filename that is sitting in the static resource is QA_Javascript.) reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806246/how-to-call-javascript-from-visualforce-page

Comment: @rao I tried that as well...no success. Below is my code, is my include script misplaced or anything? `<apex:page standardController="QA__c">
 <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.QA_Javascript}"/>  
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageMessages />
 <apex:pageBlock title="QA Scoring Form"> `

Comment: @GeorgeAlbrechtwhere are you calling the method in your static resource? Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console of the browser?

Comment: @PhilB Good catch yes I am seeing errors, specifically "myvisualforcepage" _was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from "localhost.mysite...."_: this content should also be loaded over HTTPS._...any idea how to rectify?

Comment: do you have any external site reference in you JS, if you do change it to https:// instead of http://

Comment: We don't that I am aware of, it is strictly an internal VF page used for the edit & new view of a custom object. The JS and functions used on the JS paged are loaded strictly from an internal static resource...very confused.

Answer (score 1):

Including

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.QA_Javascript}"/>
```

should work fine. Make sure that you have put the correct name though. In this case, QA_Javascript needs to be the name of the ***Static Resource*** not the name of the file itself.

Then, to reference a named function from your javascript in the onlabelclick call on a pageBlockSectionItem simply write:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem onLabelClick="YourFunctionName()">
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

No need to write the file name before your function call.

Comment: Thanks @Kyle this is exactly how I have it set up currently.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, in QA_Javascript Static resource, I saved the file as a .js, but still included  tags. Since removed and fixed, thanks for all of the help everyone.